# ASP.Net Validation not applying on Textbox while button is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to validate a textbox,but validation controls not working on button click event. i search a lot and apply different methods but the problem is still there. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```js
function ConvertToImage(btnExport) {
        html2canvas($("#myDIV")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
            var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
            $("[id*=hfImageData]").val(base64);
            __doPostBack(btnExport.name, "");
        });
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="lbl" >Product Name</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="custom_Name" Height="50px"  Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ControlToValidate="custom_Name" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Product Name" ValidationGroup="vg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Alphabets are Allowed" Font-Size="X-Large" ControlToValidate="custom_Name" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z ]*$" ValidationGroup="vg"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
             
              <!--Button for save image start-->
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfImageData" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnExport" Text="Export to Image" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="ExportToImage" OnClientClick="return ConvertToImage(this)" ValidationGroup="vg" CssClass="btnstyle" Height="50px" Width="200px" />
    <!--Button for save image ends-->
                    <asp:Button runat="server" Height="50px" Width="200px" BackColor="#ff8000" ForeColor="#ffffff" Text="Customized Designs" CssClass="btnstyle" ID="btnCustom" OnClick="btnCustom_Click" />
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the function needs to return false all the time?

Comment: I don't know why, but removing the ValidationGroup gets it to work.

Comment: Also I don't know why, but removing `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` from button gets it to work.

Comment: @jmag the return false create the problem. When i removed it. The validation works perfectly but form does not submitted to the respective page. Waht should I do?

Comment: @Joojoo. Try the answer I posted. Make sure Textbox is  grouped together with your validators and the button where the validation will be triggered. I tested the solution, it only seems that you missed the causevalidation on post bak from your button click event.

Comment: As for redirect, does it redirect to a certain page? Also, you might want to check on how to use update panels to update just part you need and not have to post/ update your whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add CausesValidation="true" to the button along with  the group.

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="custom_Name" Height="50px" Width="250px" ValidationGroup="vg"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ControlToValidate="custom_Name" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Product Name" ValidationGroup="vg"/>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Alphabets are Allowed" Font-Size="X-Large" ControlToValidate="custom_Name" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z ]*$" ValidationGroup="vg"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

 <asp:Button ID="btnExport" Text="Export to Image" ValidationGroup="vg" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="ExportToImage" OnClientClick="return ConvertToImage(this)"   CssClass="btnstyle" Height="50px" Width="200px" />
```

Comment: I tried your solution but when I clicked the button It redirect the page and not check validation even if textbox is empty

Comment: One more thing I need to validate the textbox on button that have btnExport as Id

Comment: @Joojoo I have updated the button. You have 2 buttons in your sample, sorry if that caused some confusion. Create a new button with no other properties aside from the essentials.  Just your normal <asp:Button ID="btnExport" Text="Export to Image" ValidationGroup="vg" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" />. Test the validations with that.

Comment: Remind that you need the TextBox included the ValidationGroup too.

Comment: With simple asp button that have no properties the validate controls worked but not with the btnExport that have above mentioned properties.

Comment: I also include validation group in textbox

Comment: Try it without the UseSubmitBahavior. If I remember it correctly, the Validators check for the submit behavior in order to check for validations.

Comment: I tried it but it does not worked. Then i remove the return false from javascript and it works but button's click image property does not worked

Comment: Check your F12 tools if there are errors in your console. It will tell you if your script ran into an error. It seems you already found the solution to our issue but you have a different issue now. Create a new question with updated information.  The issue you have here is caused by 2 different issues and you got one resolved. You just missed the CauseValidation trigger for you ValidationGroup.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add ValidationGroup attribute to textbox's markup as well -

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="custom_Name" ValidationGroup="vg" Height="50px"  Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
```

HTH!

Comment: I changed it but it still not validate the textbox and directly submit my form without showing the error message.